# Extract archive with tar but skip unchanged files

Tags: tar

I have a nightly process that unarchives a roughly 40 gigabytes large `tar.gz` file like this:

```
tar -xzf latest-backup.tar.gz
```

This step takes about 10 minutes, although often only a few files have changed inside the archive. I've seen that `tar` has some options to treat existing files, such as `--skip-old-files`:

```
--skip-old-files
    don't replace existing files when extracting, silently skip over them
```

Unfortunately, this also skips over files that changed and `tar` does not seem to support checking for file changes. Am I missing something, or is it really impossible to extract a large archive but only "apply the changes"?

Comment: Coincidentally, I think [this answer from yesterday](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/704547/2823) also answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same. The `-d` operation will only report what got changed between the archive and the file system.  You may have to use this information to only extract the named file. This involves a little bit of shell script. Or you can extract into a tmp dir, then use rsync to update from tmp to targetdir. Here is one example:

```
tar -zdf foo-1.8.0.tar.gz | grep 'Size differs' | sed 's/: Size differs//' | xargs tar -zxf foo`enter code here`-1.8.0.tar.gz
```

You may also need to consider files whose *Mod time differs*.  You can also look into the option *--after-date*, *--newer-mtime* for tar.